# Retrieve and display image from database using ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image

I want to retrieve an image from database and then send it to view and display it as thumbnail. Here is my code but It has some error and I can't return the image properly.
I'm using ASP.Net MVC and aspx pages.

Controller :

```
public ActionResult showImg(int id)
{
   var imageData = from m in db.Products
                   where m.ShopId == 3
                   select Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(m.Product_img.ToArray()));

   return new FileStreamResult(new System.IO.MemoryStream(imageData), "image/jpeg");
}
```

View :

```
<img src='<%= Url.Action("showImg", "image", new { id = ViewData["imageID"] } ) %>' />
```

Comment: Have you ruled out any database issue, just trying to return a hardcoded filename instead of a memory stream?

Comment: No it is just a test. I won't use hardcode in real situation.

Comment: I know you will not want to hardcode it - but are you sure that it is not a database connection issue? And is your query returning exactly what you want?

Comment: Yes my friend, I have already inserted an image to the table successfully, but now I want to retrieve it. The imageData filled with _System.Drawing.Image_ but FileStreamResult wants to return (byte[],string). Thats it.

Comment: Check this example: http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Display-Image-from-Database-in-ASP-NET-MVC

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you do not need to recreate the `Image` object in your linq statement, just return the stream and pass it your `FileStreamResult`:

```
var image = (from m in db.Products
             where m.ShopId == 3
             select m.Product_img).FirstOrDefault();

var stream = new MemoryStream(image.ToArray());

return new FileStreamResult(stream, "image/jpeg");
```

Comment: Cannot convert System.Linq.IQueryable<System.IO.MemoryStrem> to System.IO.Stream

Comment: Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.

Comment: Have updated the answer again, now performing MemoryStream construction outside of the linq statement.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot Nick. Your code is now correct. I wrote it in this way :

```
    var stream = (from m in db.Products where m.ShopId == 3 select m.Product_img).FirstOrDefault();

            return File(stream, "image/jpeg");
```